# terminal won't open after changing locale file

Tags: locale, ros

While installing a package from ROS on Ubuntu 16.04 ARM, I first configure the repositories , set up locale , setup sources.list, setup the keys, install the package , initialize rosdep and setup environmental variables. ( http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/UbuntuARM )

The locale has been set to LANG=C LANGUAGE=C LC_ALL=C LC_MESSAGES=POSIX

After the package has been installed, I restart my system and try to open the terminal to run commands, it just won't open. I click on the icon but the terminal GUI doesn't appear on the screen. How do I resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain your problem more clearly - your link appears to be broken.

Comment: @steeldriver I did edit now and sorry for the inconvenience. The link was working fine till an hour ago.

Comment: Where did you set the locale to those values and why? Ubuntu normally expects UTF-8 to be enabled.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson these parameters were set in the locale file (/etc/default/locale). One of the steps in installing ROS mentioned it. I really am not sure why it has to be set to these values specifically.

Comment: Sounds like really bad advice to me. Basically the line `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` is sufficient, and I'd suggest that you try to change it to that, if you can. (I'm assuming that the output of the `locale -a` command includes `en_US.utf8`.)

Comment: You might be able to get away with launching ROS with those environment vars on its commend line, like `LANG=C LANGUAGE=C LC_ALL=C LC_MESSAGES=POSIX ros` (or whatever its executable name is).

Comment: But I don't see anything in the installation instructions about locale...

Comment: @wjandrea    My bad . The ARM installation has that modification of locale parameters ( I edited the link in my question )

Comment: Also dbus-launch gnome-terminal has done the trick! Now my terminal works with the modified locale file as well . Thank you everyone for all your responses!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while installing some packages that modify the locale files. Had to google and roam around SO pages a lot until I found the solution [here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu).

Basically, the issue is that the *LANG* or *LC_ALL* properties need to be set properly for many GUI apps like Terminal to work. Some package changes might corrupt these properties.

You need to inspect the output of `locale` command and make sure that at least the LANG property is set to your preferred locale language. Mine is `en_US.UTF-8` or `en_IN.UTF-8`.

You can do the following steps to resolve the problem:

1.) generate a locale if it's not already available using the command,

`locale-gen <locale_name>`

You can get the names of available locales by using `locale -a`.
I would suggest

`locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

if you are not sure about your locale value.

2.) update the desired locale for `LANG` property. Use the command

`update-locale <locale_name>`

You may need to use sudo if necessary.

3.) Restart the PC and then try opening terminal.

If this doesn't work, please post the output of `locale`, `locale -a` and contents of `etc/default/locale` for more info.